# Can a Cocoa app's executable steal focus from caller?

Tags: cocoa, macos, focus, setfocus

Say I have a standard Cocoa Application call Foo.app (like the one you get just by choosing New Project > Cocoa Application in Xcode), if I open the app via a terminal using:

```
open Foo.app/
```

Then I see Foo's name on the status bar up top and its window is in focus, in front of all other apps.

If instead I directly call from the terminal the executable buried in the .app folder, like:

```
Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo
```

Nothing *appears* to happen. On inspection the app has indeed opened but it is not in focus (the terminal still is), I have to find it on the dock or find its window.

Is there any way for the Foo application to make sure its in focus when its run? Even if its run via its executable as described above?

Comment: Why do you want to override the normal behavior?

Comment: We're making an app that can be called from a MATLAB shell. And the normal behavior has it open behind the matlab windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app can "steal focus" by calling

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

See the [NSApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000012-CACCJDJC) docs for more info.

Comment: Note that this will break the ability of other applications to launch your application into the background, as might be desirable. It's not clear why you want to force this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to use this with a command line argument -stealFocus. So then from a command line script I can call: <code>Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo -stealFocus YES</code> and it will steal focus. Then the option to be a background app is still possible.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean to type:

```
open -a /Applications/Foo.app/
```

note the `-a` option

Comment: No... They do more or less the same thing. You don't need the -a, in fact, what you wrote won't work with the / after .app, you need: <code>open -a Foo.app</code>, but this is beside the point. The whole point of my question is to avoid using open, and get the app to focus on its own

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to give your app (that you're writing) this behavior -- within `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` you could call `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]`.

Comment: Note that this will break the ability of other applications to launch your application into the background, as might be desirable. It's not clear why you want to force this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps AppleScript?

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: I was hoping not to resort to this. But currently this is the best bet... It seems like a full-fledged cocoa app should have the power to do this. -Thanks

Comment: well, the question's only 10 minutes old at this time :)

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) three different ways you open (and interact with) Applications from the Terminal.

1. you can launch any Application (that is registered in LaunchServices) from the Terminal by typing `open -a ApplicationName` (note that you do not need the trailing ".app" or give any path)
2. you can open an application giving its specific path by typing `open /path/to/ApplicationName.app` (you will rarely need that, given that the applications is likely already registered in LaunchServices)
3. you can open *and interact* with the executable if you type `open /path/to/ApplicationName.app/Contents/MacOS/ApplicationName`. The difference here is that *for some Applications*, you can pass arguments or interact with them afterwards on your command line.  Go ahead and try `open /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail` for example - it will give you a debugging log in return.
4. you can interact with some applications even without using "open" by directly calling their executable; try `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin —help` for example.

So if you do want to make sure the command-line-launched application is in focus, use either method 1 or  2.