# MacRuby Accessing/Updating Text Fields

Tags: ruby, macruby

I'm fairly new to Ruby/MacRuby. I followed the stopwatch example on the MacRuby website and i used that example to try and make a simple app which takes 6 small text fields and then displays the input in another larger text field. I found a couple (although vague and very horribly documented) examples

```
class AppDelegate

    attr_accessor :window

    attr_accessor :subjectField, :messageField, :emailTo, :emailFrom, :smtpServerAddress, :smtpPort, :password

    attr_writer :subjectField, :messageField, :emailTo, :emailFrom, :smtpServerAddress, :smtpPort, :password

    def setMessageField(sender)
        @messageField += "SMTP Server Address: #{@smtpServerAddress.to_s}\n")
        @messageField += "SMTP Port: #{@smtpPort.to_s}\n")
        @messageField += "User Email: #{@emailFrom.to_s}\n")
        @messageField += "User Password: #{@password.to_s}\n")
        @messageField += "To Email: #{@emailTo.to_s}\n")
        @messageField += "Subject: #{@subjectField.to_s}\n")
    end

end
```

Obviously there is something wrong here but can anyone give me a hint in the right direction? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975325/no-input-to-nstextfield-when-running-macruby) post on here but I didn't understand it very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was going on. Within the `setMessageField` method, the `+=` operator was not valid. So I had to change it to the following. I changed the method name btw.

```
attr_accessor :window
attr_accessor :subjectField, :messageField, :emailTo, :emailFrom, :smtpServerAddress, :smtpPort, :password

def setText(sender)
    @messageField.stringValue = "SMTP Server Address: #{@smtpServerAddress.stringValue}\n"
    @messageField.stringValue = "#{@messageField.stringValue}SMTP Port: #{@smtpPort.stringValue}\n"
    @messageField.stringValue = "#{@messageField.stringValue}User Email: #{@emailFrom.stringValue}\n"
    @messageField.stringValue = "#{@messageField.stringValue}User Password: #{@password.stringValue}\n"
    @messageField.stringValue = "#{@messageField.stringValue}To Email: #{@emailTo.stringValue}"
    @messageField.stringValue = "#{@messageField.stringValue}Subject: #{@subjectField.stringValue}\n"
end
```

Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the IBOutlets are connected and all of those outlets are NSTextFields, try this:

```
class AppDelegate
    attr_accessor :window
    attr_accessor :subjectField, :messageField, :emailTo, :emailFrom, :smtpServerAddress, :smtpPort, :password

    def setMessageField(sender)
        @messageField.stringValue += "SMTP Server Address: #{@smtpServerAddress.stringValue}\n"
        @messageField.stringValue += "SMTP Port: #{@smtpPort.stringValue}\n"
        @messageField.stringValue += "User Email: #{@emailFrom.stringValue}\n"
        @messageField.stringValue += "User Password: #{@password.stringValue}\n"
        @messageField.stringValue += "To Email: #{@emailTo.stringValue}\n"
        @messageField.stringValue += "Subject: #{@subjectField.stringValue}\n"
    end
end
```

Comment: i get an error saying `'setMessageField': undefined method 'stringValue' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Verify that all of the instance variables used in setMessageField: are being assigned somewhere - most likely in Interface Builder. See the "Connect the Text Field Outlet" section of the Stopwatch example.

Comment: I followed that and connected everything but it still does not work.

Comment: @jtomscroeder: Here is an [link](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BFXlX5sCcAALuRA.png) to an image of what my outlets look like. I also changed the `small text field` back to a `text` field incase that effected it but it did not

Comment: The problem here is that setMessageField is being called before the xib is being loading, so the text fields have not been initialized yet.